# Is there any way we can use angular material menu item to look like google dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I want to use Angular Material `menu-item` to look this below.

#### Before:

[image: Before menu item]

#### After:

[image: After menu look]

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in following way

**HTML:**

```
    <md-menu>
       <md-menu-content>
           <md-menu-item>
                <div layout="column">
                    <md-icon></md-icon>
                    <span>Google +</span>
                </div>
                <div layout="column">
                    <md-icon></md-icon>
                    <span>Search</span>
                </div>
                <div layout="column">
                    <md-icon></md-icon>
                    <span>YouTube</span>
                </div>
           </md-menu-item>
       </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
```

that md-menu-item is the first row. Like that you can enter any number of rows